# Site is continuously accessing by several IPs

Tags: plugins, security

I have high traffic wordpress blog, but for last two days i am constantly getting the error "Error establishing a database connection".  I have called to my hosting customer care and they are saying that my blog is constantly accessing by some IPs addresses and they are blocking those ips.

But after 4 or 5 hours i am facing the same issues, this time spammers are attacking from other ips, every time i cannot call to my customer care to block ips.

Do we have any word press plugin or any solution for this ?

Thank you
-siva

Comment: What is the question actually? If you usually have high traffic levels why does two spammers bring your server down? To me it sounds like it is time for you to upgrade yous hosting plan.

Answer (score 0):

Any restriction on IP based on wp-admin panel ? Try to restrict Login LockDown plugin to restrict admin panel.

Comment: Hi Johns, I am already using limit login plugin

Comment: Which cache plugin you are using ? or use wp super cache with mod url rewrite settings